# Grouping by contiguous dates, ignoring weekends in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, sql-date-functions

I'm attempting to group contiguous date ranges to show the minimum and maximum date for each range. So far I've used a solution similar to this one: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/ however I'm on SQL 2000 so I had to make some changes. This is my procedure so far:

```
create table #tmp 
(
date smalldatetime,
rownum int identity
)

insert into #tmp
select distinct date from testDates order by date

select 
min(date) as dateRangeStart,
max(date) as dateRangeEnd, 
count(*) as dates, 
dateadd(dd,-1*rownum, date) as GroupID 
from #tmp
group by dateadd(dd,-1*rownum, date)

drop table #tmp
```

It works exactly how I want except for one issue: weekends. My data sets have no records for weekend dates, which means any group found is at most 5 days. For instance, in the results below, I would like the last 3 groups to show up as a single record, with a dateRangeStart of 10/6 and a dateRangeEnd of 10/20:

[image: screenshot of results]

Is there some way I can set this up to ignore a break in the date range if that break is just a weekend?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not create a permanent calendar table with a week number column?

Comment: @Martin can you elaborate on this? I could always get the week number using datepart, but I don't see how this would help alter my grouping.

Comment: Oh right I read the problem wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

I didn't like my previous idea very much. Here's a better one, I think:

1. Based on the first and the last dates from the set of those to be grouped, prepare the list of all the intermediate weekend dates.
2. Insert the working dates together with weekend dates, ordered, so they would all be assigned `rownum` values according to their normal order.
3. Use your method of finding contiguous ranges with the following modifications:

   1) when calculating `dateRangeStart`, if it's a weekend date, pick the nearest following weekday;

   2) accordingly for `dateRangeEnd`, if it's a weekend date, pick the nearest preceding weekday;

   3) when counting dates for the group, pick only weekdays.
4. Select from the resulting set only those rows where `dates > 0`, thus eliminating the groups formed only of the weekends.

And here's an implementation of the method, where it is assumed, that a week starts on Sunday (`DATEPART` returns `1`) and weekend days are Sunday and Saturday:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (date smalldatetime, rownum int IDENTITY);
DECLARE @weekends TABLE (date smalldatetime);
DECLARE @minDate smalldatetime, @maxDate smalldatetime, @date smalldatetime;
/* #1 */
SELECT @minDate = MIN(date), @maxDate = MAX(date)
FROM testDates;
SET @date = @minDate - DATEPART(dw, @minDate) + 7;
WHILE @date < @maxDate BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @weekends
  SELECT @date UNION ALL
  SELECT @date + 1;
  SET @date = @date + 7;
END;
/* #2 */
INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT date FROM testDates
UNION
SELECT date FROM @weekends
ORDER BY date;
/* #3 & #4 */
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    MIN(date + CASE DATEPART(dw, date) WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 7 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)
      AS dateRangeStart,
    MAX(date - CASE DATEPART(dw, date) WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      AS dateRangeEnd,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, date) NOT IN (1, 7) THEN date END) AS dates,
    DATEADD(d, -rownum, date) AS GroupID
  FROM @tmp
  GROUP BY DATEADD(d, -rownum, date)
) s
WHERE dates > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I had thought about inserting weekend dates to fix the range issue, but I figured it would have been more difficult than this.